# How to create NSSet of NSString into core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

All is in the question, can we create a `NSSet` (one-to-many) of a `NSString` or a `NSNumber` for exemple with CoreData ? 
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. Core Data effectively holds `NSManagedObject` instances. You can create an `NSManagedObject` that holds an `NSString` and then put that into the data store. When you fetch them, you will receive an `NSSet` collecting them.

Comment: I know we can create a MSManagedObject and then add a relationship but I want to create a NSSet of NSString.. well now i've my response. thx anyway. I don't know why somebody remove me a point. I don't think it's a stupid question.